# sink() function used with Ctrl-Enter in ESS keeps printing working directory in output file

Tags: r, ess

I am seeing a strange behavior with sink() in R, when used with ESS in Emacs.

If I sink output, by using

```
sink("file-name")
```

and I then feed lines to my R session from another buffer by using Ctrl-Enter, this seems to cause the current working directory to pop up in the sink destination file. In other words, it's as if, when I hit Ctrl-Enter,  someone had executed getwd().

This seems to be new behavior, as I don't recall encountering this in the past. Any ideas how to stop this? Executing sink() with type="output" has no effect.